Windows print queue not created correctly
I am trying to create a printer/print queue in Windows, for a printer connected to a RaspberryPi running Cups. I have followed this procedure for setting it up:https://techblog.paalijarvi.fi/2020/05/25/making-windows-10-to-print-to-a-cups-printer-over-the-network
However, it does not work. The printer is somehow defined in Windows (it appears on the "Printers and Scanners" page), but when I try to open the print queue, it fails. I have dived into the EventLog, and found several error messages, whereof I think the key ones are...
From Applications and Services Logs/Microsoft/Windows/PrintService/Admin - this is logged when I created the printer/queue:
Log Name:      Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Admin
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-PrintService
Date:          28/03/2024 02:21:51
Event ID:      808
Task Category: Initialising
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Print Spooler
User:          DESKTOP-8V33TTS\knut
Computer:      DESKTOP-8V33TTS
Description:
The print spooler failed to load a plug-in module C:\WINDOWS\system32\spool\DRIVERS\x64\3\E1YUICBCE.DLL, error code 0x5AF. See the event user data for context information.

The other one is logged when I try to open the print queue window.
From Windows Logs/Application:
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          02/06/2024 11:28:24
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: Application Crashing Events
Level:         Error
Keywords:      
User:          DESKTOP-8V33TTS\knut
Computer:      DESKTOP-8V33TTS
Description:
Faulting application name: PrintQueueActionCenter.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0xdd6d3126
Faulting module name: combase.dll, version: 10.0.22621.3527, time stamp: 0x317e0d0a
Exception code: 0xc0000602
Fault offset: 0x000000000022cf9f
Faulting process ID: 0x0x4394
Faulting application start time: 0x0x1DAB4CF36FAC4AE
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.PrintQueueActionCenter_cw5n1h2txyewy\PrintQueueActionCenter.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
Report ID: f74ea5bd-9b16-46b4-9097-5be0f13ec700
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.Windows.PrintQueueActionCenter_1.0.1.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Faulting package-relative application ID: App

Any ideas what is wrong (and perhaps even better, how to fix it)?
